# Display the original author's avatar on Community Wiki posts

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, profile-picture

I think that avatars on stackoverflow are really cool and I think that it is a fun way to express myself. That being said, when one of my posts becomes a Community Wiki post,  I'm a little sad that my avatar goes away.  Its nice that CW posts keep my name, but avatars make stackoverflow more interesting.

So how about it SO, can we keep our avatars when we create epic CW posts?

Comment: The real issue isn't that the Avatar isn't showing, it's that too many things get converted to CW when they shouldn't be. CW is supposed to be for "community collaboration", but the vast majority of wikis I see were wikied for technical reasons, "minor edits from different uses", "same user edited 10 times", "more than 30 answers"...

Answer (score 1):

Since Community Wiki posts are owned by the community, and not the original poster, displaying the avatar of the original poster is not going to work.

The only way you could do it would be to show the icon of every contributor, but (in my opinion), this would be both awkward, and (in the case of many authors) unworkable.  And it's not in the spirit of Community Wiki anyway, which sets up the post in such a way that there is no individual ownership (even among many owners).